# ERROR path is not defined ReferenceError: path is not defined gatsby-node.js

Tags: reactjs, drupal, graphql, gatsby

I am looking to fetch data from Drupal site to Gatsby via JsonApi.
I want render particular content type with all the details and info.
 I am able fetch article title from drupal site with JsonApi but now I want render image and info of that article(content type) on the another page. So i used  `createPage` method from gatsby but i am getting the following error :

`**ERROR path is not defined ReferenceError: path is not defined - gatsby-node.js:28**`

Reference Link [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JCpW.png):

My file structure

1. gatsby-node.js

```
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions, getNodesByType }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions;

  const allArticles = await graphql(`
  {
    allNodeArticle {
      nodes {
        title
        drupal_internal__nid
        path {
          alias
        }
        relationships {
          field_image {
            uri {
              url
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  `);

  allArticles.data.allNodeArticle.nodes.map(async (node) => {
    createPage({
      path: node.path.alias,
      component: path.join(__dirname, '/src/Components/Articledetails.js'),
      context: {
        id: node.drupal_internal__nid,
      }
    })
  });
}
```

2. listing.js file

```
import React from "react";
import { graphql, Link  } from "gatsby"

const listing = ({data}) => {
  return (
          data.allNodeArticle.nodes.map((info) =>
          <div>
              <div>
                  <h2><Link to={"/node/" + info.drupal_internal__nid}>{info.title}</Link></h2>
              </div>
          </div>
          )
  )
}
export const query = graphql`
{
  allNodeArticle {
    nodes {
      title
      drupal_internal__nid
      path {
        alias
      }
      relationships {
        field_image {
          uri {
            url
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
`
export default listing
```

Folder/Directory Structure is as seen in the screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Can you check this https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/19727#issuecomment-557756721 ?

Answer (score 1):

`const path = require('path')`

import the path module , it will work

Answer (score 0):

Outside the scope of the question, you should replace your `map` loop for a `forEach` loop:

```
  allArticles.data.allNodeArticle.nodes.forEach((node) => {
    createPage({
      path: node?.path?.alias,
      component: path.join(__dirname, '/src/Components/Articledetails.js'),
      context: {
        id: node.drupal_internal__nid,
      }
    })
  });
```

Double-check that `path` and `alias` are fulfilled in all article references.

Regarding your main issue (`ERROR path is not defined ReferenceError: path is not defined - gatsby-node.js:28`), is because, to use `path`, you need first to import it as a module:

```
const path = require(`path`);
```

This will allow you to do `path.join`.